# rails 4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, activeadmin

In activeadmin with ckeditor field show error: 
in chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
```

in ff

```
TypeError: d is undefined
```

indicates that string:

```
..].ltr?"ltr":"rtl"}});e.language_remove={label:d.remove,group:"language_remove",s...
```

Later everything worked. Launched bundle update, all work stopped

Comment: Got the same problem in 3.2 after bundle update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem after running the bundle update. In my case the problem was caused by ckeditor gem version 4.1.0. I moved back to version 4.0.2 by setting in my Gemile:

```
gem "ckeditor", '4.0.2'
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: Did you run bundle install after this change?